# Need help getting tikz command that dots a grid to compile and run

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to write a command to create a grid, with each integer coordinate dotted by a small black dot. The 6 parameters represent the first x, y coordinates, the second x, y coordinates, the scale of the grid (so each coordinates gets multiplied by the scale), and the dot style. I tested it not inside of the newcommand (so substituting the parameters for real numbers) and it compiled and run. However, when I put it inside a newcommand, and substitute parameters for numbers, it stops compiling.

Here is the file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{Practice tex document}
\author{Yum}

\tikzstyle{dot}=[circle, draw=black, fill=black, inner sep = 0pt, minimum size = 1mm]

\newcommand{\dotgrid}[6][1cm][dot]{
    \newcounter{i}
    \newcounter{j}
    \setcounter{i}{#1}
    \loop
        \setcounter{j}{#2}
        {\loop
            \thei
            \thej
            \node[#6] at (\the\dimexpr i*#5, \the\dimexpr j*#5) {};
            \addtocounter{j}{1}
            \ifnum\value{j}<\the\numexpr #4 + 1
            \repeat
        }
        \thei
        \addtocounter{i}{1}
        \ifnum\value{i}<\the\numexpr #3 + 1
        \repeat
    }


\begin{document}
test
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def \scale{0.5cm}
   \dotgrid{0}{0}{5}{5}{\scale}{dot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But it does not compile. Would someone please take a look at it? Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome :) // If that's all of your code, it will never compile ... until you start with a regular Latex code (`documentclass{article} ... \begin{document} ... \end{document}` ).

Comment: Hi! This isn't all of my code; I can post the full file, if necessary!

Comment: Yes, but please reduce it, so that it only demonstrates your problem. Then we can copy&run :)

Comment: Okay! I edited the post and posted the file! It is not compiling unless I remove the command and \dotgrid in the body. Thanks so much.

Comment: `\newcommand{\dotgrid}[6][1cm][dot]{...}` is not a proper syntax for `\newcommand`.  It therefore cannot compile, and I am not sure what you intend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm... I do not understand the complexity (or maybe I am missing the scope). Why you don't use the `\foreach` statement? This works:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{dot/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=2pt}}
\newcommand\dotgrid[6]{%
    \foreach \x in {#1,...,#3} 
        \foreach \y in {#2,...,#4}
            \node [#6, label={\tiny \x,\y}] at (\x*#5, \y*#5) {}; 
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \dotgrid{0}{0}{5}{5}{1cm}{dot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output from the previous code]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was not aware of the foreach statement!